# How to reshape json data into another format

Tags: json, angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

so I am getting data from my API in this format:

```
[
    {
        "lattitude": 52.57812538272844,
        "longitude": -1.7111388218750108,
    },
    {
        "lattitude": 53.043884,
        "longitude": -2.923782,
    }
]
```

I need the data to look like this, so latitude has to be 'lat' and longitude has to be 'lng' etc.

```
[{
            lat: 52.57812538272844,
            lng: -1.7111388218750108,
        },
        {
            lat: 52.3602160,
            lng: 4.8891680,
}]
```

I know there is some data missing, I will fix this later. Is there any way of doing this without changing the API. I'm using Angular-nativescript with a .net backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured a way to do it using Nativescript + Angular similar to the methods above. In the methods above I was getting errors but in this method there are no errors

This is the code I used

```
// Code to get the data
getBusinesses() {
    let baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'business/locations'
    this.http.get(baseUrl).subscribe(response => {
// Once you have your response from the api, send the data to the createData function
        this.createData(response)
    }, error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}

// Code to map the data
createData(data) {
    var newData = data.map(item => ({
            lat: item.lattitude,
            lng: item.longitude,
            title: item.address,
            subtitle: item.description,
    }))
    console.log(newData)
}
```

This is the new output

```
JS: [{
JS:   "lat": 52.57812538272844,
JS:   "lng": -1.7111388218750108,
JS:   "title": "Non deserunt labore sunt ex laboris et adipisicing ullamco officia minim.",
JS:   "subtitle": "test"
JS: }, {
JS:   "lat": 53.043884,
JS:   "lng": -2.923782,
JS:   "title": "Non deserunt labore sunt ex laboris et adipisicing ullamco officia minim.",
JS:   "subtitle": "test"
JS: }]
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the data static for you? Or is it an observable?

Assuming it is static, take advantage of the `map` operator on arrays. It transforms an array into a new array.

```
const data = [
    {
        "lattitude": 52.57812538272844,
        "longitude": -1.7111388218750108,
    },
    {
        "lattitude": 53.043884,
        "longitude": -2.923782,
    }
];

const dataYouWant = data.map((point: any) => ({lat: point.lattitude, lng: point.longitude }));
```

If it is an observable, let me know, I can help you in that regard as well.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jsonData = jsonData.map(item => ({ lat: item.lattitude, lng: item.longitude }));
```

or

```js
function renameProp(obj, oldPropName, newPropName) {
  obj[newPropName] = obj[oldPropName];
  delete obj[oldPropName];
}

jsonData.forEach(item => {
  renameProp(item, "lattitude", "lat");
  renameProp(item, "longitude", "lng");
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for both of these methods - i'm working with typescript and it says 'Property 'map' does not exist on type 'object'' - the code does work though, it just throws that error

Comment: You should be targeting es2015 or later